# RecyclerView offset drops when changing the row height in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, parallax, recyclerview-layout

Recently I've started working on custom scroll for `RecyclerView` but I've encountered a problem. I did header parallax and it worked great, but then I wanted to make rows expand when you scroll. For this method I needed to use `recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset()` it works fine for the first two items in the list but then it falls apart.

Here is an example of my code:

```
FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout) holder.itemView;
if (main != null) {
    int height = calculateHeight(offset, (position + i));
    RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) main.getLayoutParams();
    lp.height = height;
    main.setLayoutParams(lp);
}
```

So I have a function that calculates the height based on the position in layout and offset of the recyclerview. When the second item reaches `Y == 0` the offset drops for half (i.e. it drops from 1200 to 600 and then it goes on but the calculations are all wrong)

Any ideas on how to get a stable offset value or how to change it with something that is consistent with recyclerView position.

**EDIT:**

OK, I can describe the problem step by step:

- Element at position(0) of the adapter has a height of 1200
- All other elements have the default height of 300
- When user starts to scroll down, the element at position(1) starts to expand from 300 to 1200 height

--------- This is where the code starts to crack... -----------

- When element at position(1) with the new height of 1200 reaches the top of the screen (when `getTop() == 0`) offset here is around 900.
- When this same element starts to get off the screen (user is scrolling down) the offset at the point where top screen and this element collides (0,0) breaks down by the half, so offset is now 450 when it should be 900, and then it goes from 450 on, but my element at position(1) is now only half the size it should be...

Comment: Can you give a specific example of what calculations are wrong? When the offset drops by half, is that an unexpected behavior?

Comment: I edited and tried to explain the problem with words, step by step, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

OK I created a workaround for this solution and I am posting this as answer, if someone needs it in the future.

**Calculate your own offset:**

```
public int offsetForVerticalScrolling(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

    int position = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    ViewHolder mViewHolder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    View item = mViewHolder.itemView;

    int y = (int) item.getY();
    if (y < 0) y *= -1;

    if (position == 0) return y;
    else {
        int offset = y;
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
            //Add your previous item heights to offset
        }
        return offset;
    }
}
```